# What determines the order items appear in java.awt.PopupMenu?

Tags: java, trayicon

I thought it was the order they were added but for some odd reason, the "Exit" item appears above the submenu. Here is my code:

```
gram._ni.setPopupMenu(new PopupMenu());
gram._ni.getPopupMenu().add("Re-Read");
gram._ni.getPopupMenu().add("Pronunciations");
gram._ni.getPopupMenu().add("Pause");
gram._ni.getPopupMenu().add("Stop");
gram._ni.getPopupMenu().add(gram._voiceMenu);
gram._ni.getPopupMenu().add("Exit");
```

_ni is a TrayIcon. (used to be a "NotifyIcon"  when this was a C#.Net program) 
gram is an instance of the "Program" class that contains my main method.

vcr says ha can not reproduce this problem, so here is my system info:

OpenJDK version "1.8.0_121" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b14) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b14, mixed mode) 
Fedora Core 24, kernel 4.9.13-100.fc24.x86_64 
Xfce 4.12

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.  What version of Java are you using?  On what OS does this occur?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b14, mixed mode)
Fedora Core 4.9.13-100.fc24.x86_64
Xfce 4.12 

Let me try KDE and a Oral Java and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had another one of these later in my code:

```
 gram._ni.getPopupMenu().add(gram._voiceMenu);
```

I did not notice since, adding the same object will move the object rather than add a duplicate.